# What can I do to correctly display the tax owed at the end?

Tags: javascript

I have been at this for hours now. For some reason, the tax owed isn't coming up. The code appears to be correct, but for some reason, the most important result isn't coming up. What do I have to fix for it to show up? Also, is the rest of it good? Thank you for your assistance. 
The code is attached below:

```html
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Tax Program </title>
</head>

<body>
  Age Range:
  <input type="radio" name="range" id="Youngerthan21" onclick='under21 = "Y"'> Younger than 21
  <input type="radio" name="range" id="Olderthan21" onclick='over21 = "N"'> Older than 21

  <script>
    var taxrate = 0;
    var income = parseInt(incomeID.value);

    if (Youngerthan21.checked == false && Olderthan21.checked == false) {
      alert("Enter age range");
      return;

    }

    if (isNaN(income)) {
      alert("Enter valid income");
      return;

    }

    function taxFinder() {

      if (under21 == "Y") {
        if (income <= 20000) {
          taxrate = .08;

        } else if (income > 20000 && income <= 50000) {
          taxrate = .12;

        } else {
          taxrate = .20;
        }
      } else(over21 == "N") {
        if (income <= 20000) {
          taxrate = .10;
        } else if (income > 20000 && income <= 35000) {
          taxrate = .15;
        } else if (income > 35000 && income <= 70000) {
          taxrate = .25;
        } else {
          taxrate = .30;
        }

      }

      TaxOwedid.value = income * taxrate;

    }

    function clearButton() {
      incomeid.value = "";
      TaxOwedid.value = "";
      Youngerthan21.checked = false;
      Olderthan21.checked = false;

    }
  </script>

  <p>
    Income:
    <input type="text" id="incomeID">
  </p>


  <p>
    <button id="taxOwed" onclick='taxFinder()'>Process</button>
  </p>
  <p>
    Tax Owed:
    <input type="text" id="TaxOwedid" onchange=''>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button id="clearthis" onclick="clearButton ()">Clear</button>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: open you web console, fix the errors first.

Comment: I don't know how to fix those errors. Please tell me which/ how.

Comment: Start by adding a leading `0` to your numeric values, `.25` is not a valid numeric value in JavaScript

Comment: @RaulSauco That is wrong. `.25` is a valid numeric literal in JS.

Comment: @Xufox I stand corrected, thank you.

Comment: Your script is full of illegal usage of javascript syntax. You need to study javascript from scratching one by one. For example, `incomeID.value` and `Youngerthan21.checked`, nobody can't understand the syntax, though I can see what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. You weren't correctly getting the value of your inputs in the taxFinder() function. The `income` variable in taxFinder() does not exist.  You need to grab it from the input first, something like this:

`var income = document.getElementById('incomeID').value;`

See the working example below, you see the console logs as well to verify the function was being called, and the correct value is getting passed when you click "process".

Hope this helps!

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<title> Tax Program </title>
</head>

<body>
Age Range:
<input type = "radio" name = "range" id = "Youngerthan21" onclick =
    'under21 = "Y"'> Younger than 21
<input type = "radio" name = "range" id = "Olderthan21" onclick =
'over21 = "N"'> Older than 21



<p>
Income:
  <input type = "text" id = "incomeID">
</p>


<p>
  <button id = "taxOwed" onclick = 'taxFinder()'>Process</button>
</p>
<p>
Tax Owed:
<input type = "text" id = "TaxOwedid" onchange= ''>
</p>
<p>
<button id = "clearthis" onclick = "clearButton ()">Clear</button>
</p>

<script>
  var taxrate = 0;

  var income = parseInt(incomeID.value);

  if (Youngerthan21.checked == false && Olderthan21.checked == false) {
    alert("Enter age range");
    // return;

  }

  if (isNaN(income)) {
    alert("Enter valid income");
    // return;

  }

  function taxFinder() {
    console.log('taxFinder called');
    var income = document.getElementById('incomeID').value;
    console.log(income);


    if (under21 == "Y") {
      if (income <= 20000) {
        taxrate = .08;

      }
      else if (income > 20000 && income <= 50000) {
        taxrate = .12;

      }
      else {
        taxrate = .20;
      }
    }

    else (over21 == "N")
    {
      if (income <= 20000) {
        taxrate = .10;
      }
      else if (income > 20000 && income <= 35000) {
        taxrate = .15;
      }
      else if (income > 35000 && income <= 70000) {
        taxrate = .25;
      }
      else {
        taxrate = .30;
      }

    }

    TaxOwedid.value = income * taxrate;

  }
  function clearButton() {
    incomeid.value = "";
    TaxOwedid.value = "";
    Youngerthan21.checked = false;
    Olderthan21.checked = false;

  }
</script>



 </body>
```